# Teamcity suddenly cannot communicate with VCS root

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, continuous-deployment, continuous-testing

I cannot figure out why my builds on teamcity suddenly stopped communicating with my github repo.

I am given the following error:

```
Failed for the root '"Backend" {instance id=9, parent internal id=7, 
parent id=CarexsIomtBE_Backend, description: "https://github.com/../..
/#refs/heads/develop"}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not 
initialize class sun.nio.fs.LinuxNativeDispatcher
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved ?

Comment: I contacted teamcity support and apparently it's a problem with the latest JVM version. Reverting the JVM version solves the problem momentarily.

Comment: Still no solution from Jetbrains?

Answer (score 0):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-64232

The issue seems to have been fixed but not released yet (2019.2.2).

Comment: New Teamcity has been released : https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/TeamCity+2019.2.2+(build+71923)+Release+Notes